# How to remove Min and Max text in yahoo seekbar in android?

Tags: android

I am using yahoo seekbar, here min and max are automatically added text in seekbar
How to remove Min and Max text in yahoo seek bar .

XML file`

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Quality: "
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#20CE99"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:id="@+id/third_seek"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            />
```

**My Java file ` // Setup the new range seek bar**

```
  RangeSeekBar rangeSeekBar2 = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(this);
    // Set the range
    rangeSeekBar2.setRangeValues(0, 100);
    rangeSeekBar2.setSelectedMinValue(23);
    rangeSeekBar2.setSelectedMaxValue(80);


    rangeSeekBar2.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Min" + rangeSeekBar2.getSelectedMinValue(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Min" + rangeSeekBar2.getSelectedMaxValue(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    // Add to layout
    LinearLayout layout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.third_seek);
    layout3.addView(rangeSeekBar2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Given below code are work .."demo_min_label" and "demo_max_label" are give empty string..but it take space in xml.

```
<resources>
     <string name="app_name">RangeSeekBar Demo</string>
     <string name="demo_min_label"></string>
     <string name="demo_max_label"></string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

All those texts are drawn in the `onDraw()` method of `RangeSeekbar`. You should look at the code in `onDraw()` and find the lines:

```
canvas.drawText()
```

then remove or modify it